# I don't see how to add two numbers

Tags: python

```
num1 = bin(input())
num2 = bin(input())

answer = int(num1 ,2)  + int(num2,2)

print (bin(answer)) [2:]

input ("press enter to finish")
```

How do I do it so I can put 2 binary numbers in and add them up, it only lets me put one in and then it just gives me a binary representation of the 1st one.

I really need to know how to do this.

Comment: Again: your code can **only** work at all if you are using Python 2, **not** Python 3. Are you certain you are using Python 3? If so, how come you are not getting `TypeError`s here?

Comment: Your code [works perfectly for me](http://ideone.com/f9Iwge). What input do you provide to your code? What output do you see? What output do you expect to see?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.2

print (bin(int(input('>> '), 2) + int(input('>> '), 2))[2:])
```

Example usage:

```
>> 100
>> 101
1001
```

Answer (score 0):

*This solution assumes you are using Python 2.x. It's not clear if that's the case...*

- You appear to be using `bin()` incorrectly. You only need that when converting an integer to a binary string.
- You want to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`. The latter will attempt to convert the input to a number automatically, which you don't want.

So:

```
num1 = int(raw_input(), 2)
num2 = int(raw_input(), 2)

answer = num1 + num2

print bin(answer)[2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess I would do something like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

if sys.version_info[0]==2: input=raw_input

def get_bin(txt):
    while True:
        s=input(txt)
        try:
            return int(s, 2)
        except ValueError:
            print('"{}" is not a valid binary number'.format(s))

li=[]              
for i in range(1,3):
    li.append(get_bin('Enter bin number {} >>> '.format(i)))   

ans=sum(li)
w=len(bin(ans))
for i, e in enumerate(li):
    op='+' if i else ' '
    print('{}{:{w}b}'.format(op,e,w=w))   

print(' ','='*w)  
print(' {:{w}b}'.format(ans,w=w))
```

On Python 2 or 3, example:

```
Enter bin number 1 >>> 111111
Enter bin number 2 >>> 11
    111111
+       11
  =========
   1000010
```